# getCentre() not working with KML layer google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am banging my head against a wall with this. I want to display the map centre coordinates of on screen in a div. The map has a kml layer.  When I try to use **getCentre()** to get the lat & long I just get this error:

```
Object #<xi> has no method 'getCentre'
```

I'm using the following code to generate the map, with getCentre() at the end:

```
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.401712, 14.577025),
zoom: 4,
overviewMapControl: true,
overviewMapControlOptions: {
opened: true,
},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});
loadKmlLayer(src, map);
}


function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
suppressInfoWindows: true,
preserveViewport: false,
map: map,
});

var coords = map.getCentre();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is [getCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), not getCentre.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.401712, 14.577025),
  zoom: 4,
  overviewMapControl: true,
  overviewMapControlOptions: {
    opened: true,
  },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});
loadKmlLayer(src, map);
}


function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map,
  });

  var coords = map.getCenter();
```

Comment: Have you ever had a moment when you feel like a complete and utter pillock? This would be mine.